# Windows 7 - iTunes won't start minimized

Tags: windows-7, itunes, shortcuts

1) Right click on itunes short cut and select properties.
2) Select 'minimized' instead of 'normal' in the 'Run' dropdown box.
3) Click 'Apply' and then 'Close'
4) Click on modified shortcut
5) iTunes opens normally instead of minimized.

This kind of thing happens with pretty much any program I've tried to have start minimized. Same thing used to happen in WinXP too.

Comment: Same issue for me.  This has bugged me for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 2):

Well, some programs override this shortcut option. By that I mean that when they start, they explicitly decide whether they want to be minimized, maximized or "normal" not respecting what option you've set on the shortcut.

For example, the steps you've listed will work for the notepad shortcut but not for the VLC shortcut.

Comment: No, this setting means: when itunes is minimised, put it in the tray, not the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

I used a little freeware app called [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startdelay).

I dragged the (quicklaunch) 'Show Desktop' item to the list, in last place.

Now everything launches, iTunes pops up for a milisecond and minimizes.

Comment: Does that work on demand? Or is it for when you log in to your computer?